# How to generate text from excel cells?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Im dummy in VBA and I need some help. Concentrate function putting " on start and end of text, in my case I cannot use it.

I have excel file with columns A, B, C and D. On line 1 are values 1, 2, 4 and 5, on line 2 have values L, M, N, O.

[image]

I want button in column E on every line. Pressing this button calls function that generate text witch I can copy to clipboard and paste somewere as text.

If i press button on line 1, text will be:

```
Lorem ipsum 1, sir 2
dolor 4 amed 5
```

If i press button on line 2, text will be:

```
Lorem ipsum L, sir M
dolor N amed O
```

Comment: Do you need a button? Why not use a formula? What formula have you tried?

Comment: Output must have multiple lines. When I used `=CONCAT(A1;" ";A2;CHAR(10);A2;" ";C2)` output has double quotation mark (") at start and at end

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro to output a line of text similar to:

```
.formula=" Lorem ipsum " & Cells(i,1) & ", sir " & Cells(i,2) & '...
```

You will want to activate on clicking similar to:

```
Private Sub ClickAndText(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim i as integer
i = ActiveCell.Row

If Target.Address = "E"& i Then

    Range("F"&i).Formula=" Lorem ipsum " & Cells(i,1) & ", sir " & Cells(i,2) & '... 
    Range("F"&i).Copy

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could forego the button and just add the formula into column E and it will show up.  You could even do an if-string in the cell so you don't see blank space =if(isblank(A1),"Lorem ipsum " & A1 & ", sir " & B1 &... , "").